# Session not working on my host

Tags: php, session

my code is working well on another server/host but not working well on my server,

```
session_start();
include("include/session.php");

if(!$session->logged_in){
    header("Location: Login.php");
}
```

Above is my code in my index.php, instead of redirecting to Login.php, it will remain at index.php, but if i comment the include, it will header to Login.php

I get the following warning

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/xxxxx/public_html/include/session.php:1) in /home/xxxxx/public_html/include/session.php on line 40

Below is the function in my session.php and line 40 is where session_start() is

```
function startSession()
    {
        global $database;  //The database connection
        session_start();   //Tell PHP to start the session

        /* Determine if user is logged in */
        $this->logged_in = $this->checkLogin();

        /**
         * Set guest value to users not logged in, and update
         * active guests table accordingly.
         */
        if(!$this->logged_in) {
            $this->username = $_SESSION['username'] = GUEST_NAME;
            $this->userlevel = GUEST_LEVEL;
            $database->addActiveGuest($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $this->time);
        } else { /* Update users last active timestamp */
            $database->addActiveUser($this->username, $this->time);
        }

        /* Remove inactive visitors from database */
        $database->removeInactiveUsers();
        $database->removeInactiveGuests();

        /* Set referrer page */
        if(isset($_SESSION['url'])) {
            $this->referrer = $_SESSION['url'];
        } else {
            $this->referrer = "/";
        }
        /* Set current url */
        $this->url = $_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    }
```

Comment: Enable errors and see if you have any errors. Also try adding output_buffering...

Comment: maybe add what you have in `session.php`

Comment: Show us what is inside `session.php`

Comment: Could it be that the session has remembered you are logged in?

Comment: Thanks all, after enabling error with php, i have this,.........Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/xxxxx/public_html/include/session.php:1) in /home/xxxxx/public_html/include/session.php on line 40

Comment: I thinks its header problem and i put ob_start(); but not working yet

Comment: @Ademaintain : share session.php, also remove all ouput code for now try once again ?

Comment: @RishiRaut, i have updated my question, see the function on the sesssion page above

Comment: Change `session_start()` to `if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}`

Comment: or just put `exit;` before `header` to check is there any ouput or not ? share ?

Comment: @RishiRaut, after putting exit before header, the page went blank and thrown ...........Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/xxxxx/public_html/include/session.php:1) in /home/xxxxx/public_html/include/session.php on line 41

Comment: did you put what I said `Change session_start() to if(session_id() == '') { session_start(); }` ?

Comment: @RishiRaut, after putting exit before header, the page went blank and thrown ...........Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/xxxxx/public_html/include/session.php:1) in /home/xxxxx/public_html/include/session.php on line 41

Comment: I read this, I am saying  did you change `session_start()` to `if(session_id() == '') { session_start(); }` ???

Comment: Yes i did, it still didnt work

Comment: You need to check each function what you used in session.php ? that which function output's what ? or just comment by `//` and check one by one. Or may be you not shared whole session.php where is the problem.

Comment: Thanks all, it worked now, i put ob_start() on my session.php and removed the space before <?php

Comment: @Ademaintain :  So is it resolved by removing blank space as I said to remove `output`/ `echo` or `print` ? If it is so please let others know about this, who gave many downvoted.